# Automatically terminate all nodes after calling roslaunch

Tags: bash, ros

I am trying to run several roslaunch files, one after the other, from a bash script. However, when the nodes complete execution, they hang with the message:

```
[grem_node-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/956b5e54-75f5-11e9-94f8-a08cfdc04927/grem_node-1*.log
```

Then I need to `Ctrl-C` to get `killing on exit` for all of the nodes launched from the launch file. Is there some way of causing nodes to automatically kill themselves on exit? Because at the moment I need to `Ctrl-C` every time a node terminates.

My bash script looks like this, by the way:

```
python /home/user/git/segmentation_plots/scripts/generate_grem_launch.py /home/user/Data2/Coco 0 /home/user/git/Async_CNN/config.txt
source ~/setupgremsim.sh
roslaunch grem_ros grem.launch config:=/home/user/git/Async_CNN/config.txt
source /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
roslaunch rpg_async_cnn_generator conf_coco.launch
```

The script `setupgremsim.sh` sources another catkin workspace.

Many thanks!

Comment: What are your nodes doing, do they just run one operation and exit, or do some of them have something like a `rospy.spin()` or a while loop that keeps them running for a while?

Comment: They just do one thing and terminate

Comment: Can you post one of your nodes, or a link to your repo if it's online somewhere? Nodes do have the behavior that they quit once they are done, and if you've launched multiple nodes then that terminal session won't terminate until all of the nodes running from that launch file have terminated. You might have one node sticking around to do something which is preventing that session from exiting.

Comment: Why not detach each roslaunch from terminal ?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean producing loads of processes that never terminate? Probably not a good thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your advice. What I ended up doing was this; I launched my ROS Nodes from separate python scripts, which I then called from the bash script. In python you are able to terminate child processes with `shutdown`. So to provide an example for anyone else with this issue:

bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..100}
do
   echo "========================================================\n"
   echo "This is the $i th run\n"
   echo "========================================================\n"
   source /home/timo/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
   python planar_launch_generator.py
done
```

and then inside `planar_launch_generator.py`:

```
import roslaunch
import rospy

process_generate_running = True

class ProcessListener(roslaunch.pmon.ProcessListener):
    global process_generate_running

    def process_died(self, name, exit_code):
        global process_generate_running
        process_generate_running = False
        rospy.logwarn("%s died with code %s", name, exit_code)


def init_launch(launchfile, process_listener):
    uuid = roslaunch.rlutil.get_or_generate_uuid(None, False)
    roslaunch.configure_logging(uuid)
    launch = roslaunch.parent.ROSLaunchParent(
        uuid,
        [launchfile],
        process_listeners=[process_listener],
    )
    return launch


rospy.init_node("async_cnn_generator")
launch_file = "/home/user/catkin_ws/src/async_cnn_generator/launch/conf_coco.launch"
launch = init_launch(launch_file, ProcessListener())
launch.start()

while process_generate_running:
        rospy.sleep(0.05)

launch.shutdown()
```

Using this method you could source any number of different catkin workspaces and launch any number of launchfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

(1) For each launch you put in a separate shell script. So you have N script
In each script, call the launch file in xterm.   xterm -e "roslaunch yourfacnylauncher"

(2) Prepare a master script which calling all N child script in the sequence you want it to be and delay you want it to have.

Once it is done, xterm should kill itself.

Edit. You can manually kill one if you know its gonna hang. Eg below

```
#!/bin/sh
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

## start ROScore using systemd or rc.local using lxtermal or other terminals to avoid accident kill. Then run the part which you think gonna hang or create a problem. Echo->action if necessary

```
xterm -geometry 80x36+0+0 -e "echo 'uav' | sudo -S dnsmasq -C /dev/null -kd -F 10.5.5.50,10.5.5.100 -i enp59s0 --bind-dynamic" & sleep 15
```

## Stupid OUSTER LIDAR cant auto config like Veloydne and will hang here. other code cant run

```
killall xterm & sleep 1
```

Lets just kill it and continuous run other launches

```
xterm -e "roslaunch '/home/uav/catkin_ws/src/ouster_driver_1.12.0/ouster_ros/os1.launch' os1_hostname:=os1-991907000715.local os1_udp_dest:=10.5.5.1"
```

Comment: So I tried this, but it actually causes the exact same behavior - except I know have more than one terminal open.

Comment: I Updated a sample in the Edit. I encounter a similar thing when I deal with Ouster LIDAR drivers. They need a series of command to run first, b4 calling the LIDAR ROS driver and some of their command will cause hangs or not running. This is how I deal with it.